# Hide option to create meeting workspaces for new sites created

Tags: 2010, content-type

I already know how to iterate over all sites in a site collection and hide the option to create meeting workspaces.

http://pastie.org/3349098

This will work however for already created sites.

What about if I want to disable this for new created sites?  How can I achieve this?

Comment: I suppose this needs to be  done at provisioning time? any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your method will only affect existing Event lists (list type 106). If people create new lists after they will be able to create workspaces there.

If you have publishing enabled on those sites, you can remove the different workspaces templates from the list of allowed templates for subsites.

Alternatively perhaps something can be done with a feature stapler on the workspace templates.. Not sure what though :(

**Edit**: You can remove the Create Site right from a group of users, they will no longer be able to create workspaces (nor any other type of site...). Unfortunately they will still see the option and it will give them an error if they attempt it.

You can also try [this method](http://moblog.bradleyit.com/2009/07/hideremove-workspace-from-sharepoint.html) (it only hides the checkbox). They can still create workspaces from the site action menu.

Comment: that could be done by an event receiver in list adding or something?

Comment: The problem is that a workspace is a type of site. People can create them from events, but they can also create them as any other site template. If you just want to block creation from events, you can try with a ItemAdding/ItemUpdating and force the "Create a workspace" field to false.

Comment: how can I remove the allowed templates?